# No Network Security Config specified

Tags: java, android, http, post

знаю, что тут уйма ответов на мой вопрос, но я либо неправильно пробую, либо опять же неправильно пробую. 
Разрабатываю приложение на android. Требуется связаться с базой данной, так как напрямую небезопасно, реализовываю через post-запрос и последующую обработку в PHP на сайте. Вроде все сделал, но запрос не посылается уходит в catch, а в логах такая строка:

```
2019-04-05 12:11:39.920 7823-7823/com.potapov.club17 D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
```

В манифест вписал доступ к интернету, также как сказано в Google Документации добавил ссылку на протокол безопасности в папке xml, так же и описал этот протокол. Сейчас приложу все по порядку.

network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config usesCleartextTraffic="false">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">ссылка, которую я убрал, чтобы не спамили</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.potapov.club17">
    <meta-data android:name="android.security.net.config"
        android:resource="@xml/network_security_config" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

А вот так я пытаюсь послать post-запрос:

```
 protected Void doInBackground() {
        try {
            String myURL = "ссылка"; //убрал, чтобы не спамили запросами
            String parammetrs = "name=Android&tel=8890989&date=10.10.2019&time=10:10&message=dsdsdsd";
            byte[] data = null;
            InputStream is = null;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(myURL);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setDoInput(true);

                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(parammetrs.getBytes().length));
                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                data = parammetrs.getBytes("UTF-8");
                os.write(data);
                data = null;

                conn.connect();
                int responseCode= conn.getResponseCode();

                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                if (responseCode == 200) {
                    is = conn.getInputStream();

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; // Такого вот размера буфер
                    // Далее, например, вот так читаем ответ
                    int bytesRead;
                    while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                    data = baos.toByteArray();
                    String resultString = new String(data, "UTF-8");
                } else {
                }



            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                //resultString = "MalformedURLException:" + e.getMessage();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                //resultString = "IOException:" + e.getMessage();
            } catch (Exception e) {

                date.setText("Exception:" + e.getMessage());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Как настроить протокол безопасности нормально? Или в данном случае не в нем дело? Требуется просто посылать запрос с данными, которые я потом соберу с полей приложения.

Comment: UPDATE: Запрос посылаю на сертифицированный HTTPS

Comment: Какой протокол?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы неверно задали конфигурацию для приложения в манифесте.
Документация говорит что это атрибут тэга `application`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ... >
<application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
                ... >
    ...
</application>
```

У вас же это мета-данные.
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html